# Using TLS 1.2 and java 6

Tags: tomcat, java, tls

We have a legacy web application that runs in a tomcat under java 6 - an upgrade to 7 or 8 is currently infeasible. We now have a requirement to connect, as a client, over TLS 1.2 however java 6 only supports 1.0. We use Apache as our web-server and OpenSSL for incoming connections and this happily supports TLS 1.2 etc.

Have you come across similar before, or can you comment on the following potential work arounds:

- Loopback to localhost (or otherwise redirect) and use OpenSSL to create a TLS 1.2 connection,

  - effectively an internal proxy
  - can openssl be a client?
  - do we need s_client?
- Use our current the firewall to upgrade the connection

  - this would need to be selective
  - Obviously implementing this will depend on the firewall
- Use “Bouncy Castle” (https://www.bouncycastle.org/)

Comment: Do you mean that Tomcat needs to actually see the 1.2 connection or is it enough to terminate TLS on Apache?

Comment: The problem in this instanced is that the java application is acting as the client so not using apache

Comment: ok, now I get it: Your web application will connect to some other application and needs to talk TLS 1.2... Not sure if such a workaround is worth going after. Establishing a proxy - either a newer Java-version or OpenSSL will certainly increase complexity, lower maintainability and introduce many opportunities for getting it wrong and making the whole system less secure than expected with a newer version of the protocol. Good luck is all I can say. I'd strongly opt for the upgrade of the current application. Any effort there reduces complexity, rather than increase it.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to upgrade as the application will not function with newer java versions and the fixes are needed are too significant to implement in a legacy application.